# Custom Lookup style Issue

Tags: lightning

standard page appearance is changing because of the custom lookup in Lightning

```
<ltng:require scripts="/resource/Lgt_InputLookup/js/jquery-2.2.4.min.js, 
 /resource/Lgt_InputLookup/js/bootstrap.min.js, /resource/typeahead" 
 styles="/resource/Lgt_InputLookup/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.initTypeahead}" />
```

If I remove below line

```
styles="/resource/Lgt_InputLookup/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
 afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.initTypeahead}" />
```

standard page appearance will not change. But it causes problem in displaying Magnifying glass.

Whats the root cause? any alternate styles are required to resolve this Issue?

Comment: Figure out which css is causing the Magnifying glass using developers tool of browsers then use the same css style in your component directly to show the magnifying glass and loose dependency on the bootstrap css file.

Comment: OR
figure out which css is causing to distort the standard page and remove those styles from the bootstrap css file.

Comment: This style causes problem in standard page. styles="/resource/Lgt_InputLookup/css/bootstrap.min.css" afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.initTypeahead}" /> . If I remove this line right magnifying glass also remove..Instead of this style any alternative style is there?!!!...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can customized your lightning lookup

```
<style>
.lookupInput a{
position: absolute;
width: 33px !important;
margin-left: 5px;
background-image: url(/img/setup/search-icon.png) !important;
background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
background-position: center !important;
display: inline-flex !important;
}
.lookupInput input{
width:91% !important;
}
.lookupInput a img{
display:none !important;
}

</style>

<apex:inputField styleClass="slds-lookup__search-input slds-input" value="{!con.accountId}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the style section of Lightning component for defining the style instead of calling a separate stylesheet.

You could optionally try calling standard search icon from SLDS

```
<lightning:icon iconName="utility:search"/>
```